# Where can I change the photo for posting to Google Groups?

Tags: google-plus, google-groups, google-account-profile

Google groups leads me to my Google+ profile, but the picture on Google+ is different from the thumbnail. Where can I change my actual Google Groups picture? See:

When I post a new topic and want to join the group:

[image: join message]

My Google+ profile:

[image: screen shot of G+ profile]

I can't find any place on my Google+ profile where that old picture appears. Suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

Check your Gmail settings. I know it sounds weird, but it worked for me:

Gmail -> Settings -> General -> My Picture.

[image: Changing Gmail Profile Picture]

Comment: This worked for me as well, even though I had previously set my profile picture at [Google aboutme](https://aboutme.google.com/)