# How can I get my thumbnail to display by my posts to Google Groups?

Tags: gmail, google-groups

I want my thumbnail to display when I post to a Google Group. It works when I send email from one of my Gmail accounts, but not from the other. All three messages here are from me - the first one is from one Gmail account, and the other two are from another:

[image: screen shot of message list]

I found what seemed to be the answer to this dilemma [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/88066/where-can-i-change-the-photo-for-posting-to-google-groups), but it doesn't work for me; I already have a picture set there:

[image: screen shot of profile picture]

What do I need to do yet to get something other than the generic blue avatar man to represent me, specifically the image that displays directly above (tuxified me)?

TLDR/Reader's Digest version: I want the punified version of picture of me in a tux to replae the light blue "man" to the left of the "How do you deal with..." email topic.